# hibernate not updating in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i have a problem that my project is based on spring mvc integrated with hibernate.in this update is not working..
**dao**

```
   @Override
        public void updateAuditorium(Auditorium auditorium) {
        openSession().update(auditorium);
    }
```

**service**

```
@Transactional
    public void update(Auditorium auditorium) {
    auditoriumDAO.updateAuditorium(auditorium);

    }
```

**configuration**

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auditoriumbooking" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.company.product.model</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

After function executed noting happend.

Comment: Could you provide us with any console logs? Can't figure out anything with what you have put up here.

Comment: you mean tomcat log?

Comment: you need to commit the transaction.

Comment: im using sessionFactory.how can i commit transation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using sessionFactory, you have to use `Transaction` for db manipulation.
You have to create the session, then begin a transaction in the session and do the db manipulation and then save it to the database through committing the transaction

```
Transaction transaction = null;
Session session = null;
try {
    //create the session object with openSession() and then begin transaction on session         
    session = sessionFactory().openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(auditorium);
    transaction.commit();

} catch(HibernateException e) {
    transaction.rollback();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

EDIT: 
After the question edit:

you are using `@Trasactional` annotation. 
so you have to create a `HibernateTransactionManager` bean(if not created already) and use

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Create a `HibernateTransactionManager` & define `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in

> application-context.xml

Answer (score 1):

All the insert/ update functions must be within a transaction

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    //update/insert operations here

    session.update(auditorium);

    tx.commit();

    session.close();
```

If you are handling the session bu yourself (`factory.openSession()`), then you can perform read only operations without a transaction. However, if you configure session handling in hibernate configuration file, then hibernate will open and close the session for you and a transaction is required even for read only operations. In that case you have to write `factory.getCurrentSession()`. The transaction is mandatory because hibernate closes the session automatically when it detects end of a transaction.